# Read data from file XML in SparkSession Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I put file on the screen below, "PostHistory.xml"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThZT1.png)

How to write a command to put this data in Spark Dataframe?

I tried by this code:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd

# inicjalizacja SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("xml-to-dataframe").getOrCreate()

# wczytanie pliku XML do struktury ElementTree
xml_data = ET.parse('PostHistory.xml')
root = xml_data.getroot()

# utworzenie listy słowników, która będzie użyta do stworzenia DataFrame
data = []

# iteracja po elementach w strukturze ElementTree i dodanie atrybutów do listy data
for child in root:
    data.append(child.attrib)

# stworzenie DataFrame z listy słowników przy użyciu biblioteki pandas
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# utworzenie Spark DataFrame przy użyciu funkcji parallelize z modułu pyspark.sql
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)

# wyświetlenie Spark DataFrame
spark_df.show()
```

But I get this error instead:

```py
TypeError: field Comment: Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DoubleType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'>
```

How modify this code to put the data in df?

Comment: Please post errors & source code as code, not as example - edit your question...

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! Try no to add images, its easier to operate on code which can be copy/pasted. Here you may find more details on how to add good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Nevertheless, in screenshots i see exception "can not infer schema from empty dataset" so probably your path to file is wrong

Comment: @alexott ok I changed

Comment: Have you seen the spark-xml library? https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml/